# Statistical methods in experiments

Tags: statistics, error-propagation

I'm currently facing a huge problem in manipulating raw data from an experiment.

Suppose I have the set of data:
 $$T_1=6.12 \pm 0.001s,\\ T_2=4.90875 \pm 0.001s, \\ T_3=3.9 \pm 0.001s, \\ T_4=3.69 \pm 0.01s$$
Height $h$ is $20m$.
Suppose then that the velocity $v$ is $h/t$.
How would I go about computing ${v}^{2}$ while taking into account the uncertainties?

Comment: t1=6.12+/-0.001s
t2=4.90875+/-0.001s
t3=3.9+/-0.001s
t4=3.69s+/-0.001s
No t5 exists. 
It was a typo

Comment: I have edited my above comment as well as the OP

Comment: I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

The error compounds, but you can still give error bounds. For example in the first case we have 
$$\frac{20}{6.121}\le v\le\frac{20}{6.119}$$
so
$$\left(\frac{20}{6.121}\right)^2\le v^2\le\left(\frac{20}{6.119}\right)^2$$

In decimal form this gives you
$$10.676<v^2<10.684$$